# How To Check for an Index & Drop + Create if exists in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

I am writing a schema upgrade script for a product that depends on an Oracle database. In one area, I need to create an index on a table - if that index does not already exist.
If it exists, then I need to drop it (because altering existing index doesn't allow adding another column) and create with the same name. I am using the following script -

```
DECLARE
   i INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO i FROM user_indexes WHERE index_name = 
'ELEMENTS_5_NDX';
IF i = 0 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('
    CREATE INDEX ELEMENTS_5_NDX
    ON elements_l
    (scode ASC, pkey ASC, START_DATE ASC, OPP_SEX_IND ASC)
    ');
ELSE
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('DROP INDEX ELEMENTS_5_NDX');
    COMMIT;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('
    CREATE INDEX ELEMENTS_5_NDX
    ON elements_l
    (scode ASC, pkey ASC, START_DATE ASC, OPP_SEX_IND ASC)
    ');    
 END IF;
 END;
 /
```

I'm getting following error - 
Error report:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
ORA-06512: at line 9
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"

Please suggest some tips.

Comment: My issue is in the else condition - when the index exists. The script says the name is already used, but I've just dropped it, also used Commit, but that didn't work too.

Comment: Is the index part of primary key?

Comment: No, just an index to identify a unique combination of rows.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the `ELSE` part? Can you try to run `SELECT index_name FROM user_indexes WHERE upper(index_name) = 
'ELEMENTS_5_NDX'` and post the result?

Comment: Yeah there's a discrepancy - when I am trying to find the index in user_indexes, the count is 0, but in all_objects I can find the index, maybe that is why it causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked -

```
 DECLARE
  i INTEGER;
 BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO i FROM all_objects WHERE index_name = 
   'ELEMENTS_5_NDX' and owner = sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' );
   IF i > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('DROP INDEX ELEMENTS_5_NDX');
   END IF;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('CREATE INDEX ELEMENTS_5_NDX ON elements_l
   (scode ASC, pkey ASC, START_DATE ASC, OPP_SEX_IND ASC)');    
END;
/
```